# How to Find Last Occurrence of XML Tag before Another Tag

Tags: java, xml

I'm working with some XML provided by a third party that isn't structured to support a particular need we have.  This file has empty `<PRTPAGE>` tags that can occur anywhere within the markup.  I'm trying to find the last `PRTPAGE` tag that occurs before a particular starting tag (in this case it's a `RULE` tag).

Because the two tags are not guaranteed to have any common parent other than the root element, I'm not sure how to do this.  It's just as likely the `PRTPAGE` tag I'm looking for is deeply nested in the `RULE` tags previous sibling as it is that it's the direct previous sibling of the `RULE` tag. I'm currently using `org.w3c.dom` in Java to parse the XML, but I'm open to using other libraries.

Edit:

It's hard to include a full example because the files are so long.  The XML is designed to mimic a print document.  The `PRTPAGE` tag represents a page break, which can occur virtually anywhere, and includes an attribute for the page number of the following page.  I'm trying to figure out the page number each `RULE` tag starts on.

Comment: Can you provide a sample xml that makes your requirements clearer?

Comment: Looks like you need `XPP` parser. http://www.xmlpull.org/v1/download/unpacked/doc/quick_intro.html. It goes top to bottom and you can stop in between rather than loading the entire XML as regular parser do.

Comment: You should be able to use the [preceding axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#axes) in an XPath (`org.w3c.dom.xpath`) to select the first preceding `PRTPAGE` element: `//RULE/preceding::PRTPAGE[1]`

Comment: @DanielHaley, thank you.  I think this is exactly what I need.  At some point, I need to really learn XPath instead of just picking up bits and pieces when I need them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XStream library. [About](https://x-stream.github.io/)

Read the 'alias' for `PRTPAGE` and `RULE` as `xstream.alias("PRTPAGE", String.class);`

Now, you would also need to store and read the line breaks and put that into a `Map<Integer, String>` together with the alias, so that you find the last `PRTPAGE` tag with a higher line break than the next `RULE` tag